# Тормозит приложение при наборе текста

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть приложение, использующее React в связке с Redux

Везде, где идет набор текста в input или textarea приложение начинает тормозить. Люди жалуются.

Почитал, что надо отключить devtools - отключил.

Дальше идут рекомментации по оптимизации shoultComponentUpdate, но тут надо обновлять каждый раз, т.к. каждая буква должна пропечататься.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с похожей проблемой?
Может ли влиять на это размер состояния приложения?
Состояние приложения объединяется из нескольких reducer'ов (7-8 штук)
Каждый reducer может быть как Immutable.js объектом, так и простым js объектом.

На onChange вызывается один метод, который всплывает вверх по вложенным компонентам реакта на 3-4 уровня. 
Затем вызывается один экшн, который возвращает разу же объект, содержащий только name и value. Дальше один reducer его подхватывает и изменяет состояние через Immutable.setIn в одну строку.

Все происходит довольно плоско и я не знаю где можно оптимизировать.
Помогите, пожалуйста, кто чем может.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [uncontrolled компоненты](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). Изменение содержимого input не приводит к изменению состояния компонента, соответственно не вызывается лишний раз метод render(), при этом, буквы в input пропечатываются. А значение input доступно по ссылке this.input.value, и вы можете использовать его, например, при отправке формы.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.input.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" ref={(input) => this.input = input} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: А как при инициализации компонента положить туда value из store?

Comment: Можно использовать свойство инпута `defaultValue = {valueFromStore} `

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю еще свой вариант.

Чтобы не напрягать redux, я записываю данные в state компонента через this.setState, а отправка в redux идет через задержку, либо по другому условию.

```
handleChange(e) {
    let self = this,
        event = {};

    // продолжаем извращаться
    for(var k in e) event[k]=e[k];

    let newState = {};
    for(var k in this.state) newState[k]=this.state[k];

    newState.field[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);

    clearTimeout(this.changeTimeout);
    this.changeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        self.props.onChange(event, {
            name: event.target.name,
            value: event.target.value
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Попутно задам вопрос: Как можно оптимизировать этот код?